# How to change the format of a percentage number?

Tags: javascript, html, localization, format, percentage

I am localizing a static html website from English into French using Trados. Trados shows me correctly all the segments I have to translate, but on the website there is a percentage progressing when I scroll down (it starts from 0%, 0.1%, 0.2%... to 90.1%) which does not appear on Trados and I have to change them in 0 %, 0,1 %, 0,2 % and so on. In other words I have to replace the dot with a comma and add a non-brake space before the "%" symbol.
In which file do I have to change that (html? javascript?) and how? Can anyone please help me?

In the html file I can see:

```
<div class="section" data-scroll="updatePercentNumber" data-begin="0" data-end="0.16">
```

and then:

```
<div class="section" data-scroll="updatePercentNumber" data-begin="0.16" data-end="0.55">
```

and then:

```
<div class="section" data-scroll="updatePercentNumber" data-begin="0.55" data-end="0.901">
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't create a custom HTML filetype for your project then the easiest way is to edit the div parser rule and add a new attribute called "data-end".  Then set it as translatable.
[New attribute on div parser rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0IlpA.png)

Make sure you do this **before** you process the file for translation as it's too late to change your existing project.